# Failed to create adb client using shell adb command

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flipper

I moved from react-native-debugger to flipper. I configured it and the state and components can be seen. But I cant see the consolg.logs. It also shows this error.

```
Failed to create adb client using shell adb command. Trying with adbkit.
Error: Command failed: /opt/android_sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server

/bin/sh: 1: /opt/android_sdk/platform-tools/adb: not found
```

I have installed adb. adb devices shows me the device list.

What am I doing wrong here?